# Why does the following test says the file does not exist?

Tags: bash

Given

```
$ PSEXE="$(whereis ps)" 
$ echo $PSEXE
ps: /nix/store/06sa9q0xmd3rhqbd0pb5kpdhz68vq2pk-system-path/bin/ps
$ file  /nix/store/06sa9q0xmd3rhqbd0pb5kpdhz68vq2pk-system-path/bin/ps
/nix/store/06sa9q0xmd3rhqbd0pb5kpdhz68vq2pk-system-path/bin/ps: symbolic link to /nix/store/1mhhpcb9dxyila8jqa3x1cqj9nd3l4sg-procps-3.3.16/bin/ps
```

Why does the following test says  the file does not exist?

```
$ if [ ! -x "$PSEXE" ]
> then
> echo yes
> fi
yes
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Let's deconstruct your script:

```
PSEXE="$(whereis ps)" 
echo "$PSEXE"
```

On my system this returns something sufficiently similar in shape to yours that we can continue:

```
ps: /bin/ps
```

Note specifically that the variable `$PSEXE` contains the string `ps: /bin/ps`.

You then have your script with its conditional expression:

```
if [ ! -x "$PSEXE" ]
```

that is effectively evaluated by the shell as

```
if [ ! -x 'ps: /bin/ps' ]
```

There is no file `ps: /bin/ps` so the executable test fails, the negation applies, and the resulting expression evaluates as `true`.

---

If you simply want to find out if an executable exists in the `$PATH`, you can use `type`:

```
PSEXE='ps'
if type "$PSEXE" >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo "Executable exists"
fi
```

With `bash` you can extract the target executable easily enough:

```
PSEXE=`type -p ps 2>/dev/null`
```

but with POSIX `sh` it's a little more complex:

```
PSEXE=`type ps 2>/dev/null | sed -n 's/^[^ ]* is //p'`
```